# Form that creates posts

Tags: plugin-recommendation, forms

How can I create a form that allows people to submit questions / ideas that once submitted creates a post in wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excellent [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) plugin makes this extremely easy. It's not free (starts at $39), but I highly recommend it.
*I am not affiliated with the Gravity Forms team in any way - I'm just a satisfied customer!*

Comment: I went with the Gravity forms. Found a coupon online and saved a few bucks. It works well. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in free, there's also [TDO Mini Forms](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/) (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/) and [cformsII](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/) (http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/)