# Allow anonymous users to post to my site for moderation

Tags: posts, users, moderation

I'm in need of the ability to allow anyone (they don't have to login) to fill out a form with email and a textarea and submit it to my site. This form would be treated as a post and appear somewhere for me to moderate. If i hit publish, it would be published to my site like any other post i wrote.

Is there a plugin that allows me to do this or do i need to code it myself, if the latter, how would i go about doing that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question has been asked many many many many times. Just as one example: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5245/form-that-creates-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you?

http://perishablepress.com/user-submitted-posts/

Comment: nice find, good work

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) will enable you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

User Submitted Posts plugin mentioned above is actually perfect. It allows image uploads, the ability to select a category and a lot of control for the site owner.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give [Formidable](http://formidablepro.com/) a shot. The plugin allows custom building on a form by form basis which means that you can have as many forms as you want.

Users can create new pages or posts via forms that you can moderate and publish, or auto-publish if you wish.

On top of all of that, it generates a shortcode for every form you have which you can easily insert into a page using the Formidable insert option in the editor.

Form fields include:

- File Upload
- ReCaptcha
- Image URL's
- Passwords
- Checkboxes
- Dropdowns (select menus)
- Radio Buttons
- Text Input
- Textbox input
- Email address fields
- ...and more

Note:The feature that allows users to post a new page or post is only available with the Pro version. Fortunately it's only $37 for a single license or $97 for an unlimited license.